# How to return SQL rows with the largest year from date field only?

Tags: mysql, date

So I have multiple fields in my database and one of which is `date`. The `date` field is of `date` datatype and I need to return only those values which have the largest `year` value within the `date` field.

So far I've done this:

```
$files = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE unpublish=0 AND year(date) ORDER BY files.date DESC");
```

Now obviously it's not enough, how could I force it to treat `year(date)` to return only largest values?

Comment: Look like pure [tag:mysql]. Is there a reason for the [tag:sql-server] tag as well (they're separate products)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM files 
WHERE unpublish=0 
AND year(date)=(SELECT MAX(YEAR(date)) FROM files) 
ORDER BY files.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM files 
WHERE unpublish=0 
and year(date)=(SELECT MAX(YEAR(date) FROM files)
ORDER BY files.date DESC
```

So it would be like

```
$files = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files 
    WHERE unpublish=0 
    and year(date)=(SELECT MAX(YEAR(date) FROM files)
    ORDER BY files.date DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to write like this:

```
$files = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files
                      WHERE unpublish=0
                      AND date=(
                          SELECT YEAR(date)
                          FROM files
                          ORDER BY date DESC
                          LIMIT 1)
                      ORDER BY files.date DESC");
```

Or may be you want to select the max date from SELECT command like:

```
$files = mysql_query("SELECT col1, col2, col3, max(YEAR(date)) AS date
                      FROM files
                      WHERE unpublish=0
                      ORDER BY files.date DESC");
```

where col1, col2, col3 is manualy selected columns.